# Scrapy extensions directory permission issue

Tags: python, scrapy

I made a custom extension in `Scrapy`, and it's in folder `extensions` (`extensions` is in the project folder which contains `spider` folder, `pipelines.py`, etc). It works on `Cloud9`, but got this error message once I uploaded it to my server:

`ImportError: No module named extensions.my_extension`

The path in my `settings.py`

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'wow.extensions.my_extension.MyExtensionClass': 500,
}
```

I guess it's related to the directory permission, as it will work if I move the extension file to the project directory (same directory of pipelines.py) and change the `settings.py` accordingly.

Folder permission is 755 and extension file is 664, both of them are same on `cloud9`.

Thanks.

Comment: if you know what's the issue why are you asking? Why not simply set proper permissions?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @PawelMiech 'what's the proper permissions?' it's what I'm asking. The same permissions work on `cloud9` but not on my server.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida How to make the extension script in `extension` folder work, rather than saving it in the project root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out the answer. It has nothing to do with permissions, all I need to do is to make an empty `__init__.py` file.